# Successive bootstrap accordion entries are increasingly large?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to display a list of people from an SQL server in an accordion (expandable list).

My problem is that there is an increasing amount of whitespace between consecutive entries in the accordion, which I can't get rid of.

**Its easiest to see it in action:** http://ec2-54-200-151-237.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/#

When the whitespace is clicked the tab above is opened, which is some clue to what is going wrong - however I am quite new to html and javascript.

Here is the javascript that creates the new panel:

```
function create_panel(first_name, last_name, idx){
    var $template = $(".template");
    var $newPanel = $template.clone();
    $newPanel.find(".collapse").removeClass("in");
    $newPanel.find(".accordion-toggle").attr("href",  "#" + String(idx))
             .text(last_name+" "+first_name);
    $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", idx).addClass("collapse").removeClass("in");
    return $newPanel;
}
```

And the html panel group element:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
  <div class="panel panel-default template" style="display:none">
    <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse20" style="width:100%;">
      <a class="panel-title"> 
      Mr. Template <span class="label label-danger" style="float:right">Urgent</span>  
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse20" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me see where the problem is, I'd be extremely grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this just after posting.

The fact that the extra whitespace was compounding tipped me off:

The javascript was referring to the last created item `.template` every time it made a new entry - hence the compounding. I added `id=template` to the panel element and changed the javascript refererence to `#template`, and the accordion now looks normal.

Comment: Was just about to post saying there was duplication going on somewhere! glad you figured it out.